# Suppose A be s symmetric and positive definite $n\times n $ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let A be s symmetric and positive definite $n\times n $ matrix show that $\|x\|_A=\sqrt {x^TAx}$ is a norm  for vectors $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$

I need to prove this by the eigenvalues and eigenvector decomposition of symmetric positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A = U \Lambda U^T $, where $U$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries on the diagonal. Then
$\|x\|_A = \| \sqrt{\Lambda} U^T x\|_2$, and since $\sqrt{\Lambda} U^T$ is
invertible, it follows that $\|\cdot\|_A$ is a norm.